# iron_worker zip/zip (LoadError) error using iron_worker_ng gem

Tags: ironworker, iron

I am receiving this error when I'm using ironworker's **iron_worker** gem to upload and build my worker.
iron_worker upload  results in

```
error:/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- zip/zip (LoadError)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was a recent change to the rubyzip gem that required a dependency lock on the iron_worker_ng gem.

to fix this update to the latest version by running the command.

```
gem update iron_worker_ng
```

Your gem version should be 
iron_worker_ng (1.0.2)

You can test this by running

```
iron_worker -v
```

It should look like **iron_worker_ruby_ng-1.0.2 (iron_core_ruby-1.0.1)** 
as of 09/12/13.